# How can I set an app widget preview image if and only if the device being used is running Honeycomb?

Tags: android, reflection, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-appwidget

I'm working on an app that runs on both 3.0 devices and non-3.0 devices.  I'd like to use the app widget preview function introduced in Honeycomb, but because it is not available to non-Honeycomb devices, I can't simply declare the `previewImage` field in my `widget_info.xml` file.

I'm assuming I need to use reflection to test if the field is available and set it if it is.  However, I don't know where in my code I would perform this test.  Where exactly should I set the `previewImage` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to target SDK version 11 for this to work.

Simply change `targetSdk` to 11 and change library and everything should work!

Comment: I've already targeted SDK 11, but my library is still set to my minSdkVersion which is 7.  If I change the library to 11 won't that remove support for pre-3.0?

Comment: Nope, as long as you don't use any 3.0 only classes or methods you are fine (XML attributes doesn't matter). Set the library to 11 and it should work.

Comment: Great I'll give it a try later today. Thanks!

Comment: Alright - I can't seem to figure out how to change my library without changing my minSdkVersion.  If I remove library version 7, and try to add a new library, I'm not given a choice which one to use.

Comment: Would you mind posting what you did to get it to work for others to see? Thank you.